# Windows 8 refresh from partition disk

Tags: windows-8, system-reserved-partition, windows-8-refresh

Here's my situation:

- I bought Win8 from the internet when it was 30 dollars.
- I upgraded it to Win 8.1
- I do not have a CD/DVD drive.
- In order to install it, I created a disk partition from my 64GB SSD and placed all the installation files in there (Z:\ partition).
- As a result, I have C:\ with 55GB for the OS to run and 3GB in the Z:\ as my Windows Installer.
- To install, I simply booted the Z:.

Today, I turned on my computer and it got the blue screen of death with a sad face. I tried to use System Restore without any luck.

My last resort is to use Windows Refresh.

- When I try to refresh it, my computer asks for a Windows Media (CD/USB?).
- When I boot the Z:\ and try to refresh it, it asks me to choose which boot I want to repair. Of course, I'm going to choose the Windows 8.1 boot option. It then tells me that **The drive that Windows is installed is locked. Unlock the drive and try again.**

How can I unlock the Windows drive (C:) and repair it from Z:?

Note: My Windows will not start. Everytime I try, it crashes under the 0xc0000021a error and no System Restore option fixed it.

Comment: I assume you still get a BSOD even if you boot into Safe Mode?

Comment: Yes, tried Safe Mode and no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to turn on my computer on again. With my experience about this sort of things, I know that what fixed my problem was a whole bunch of set of actions rather than just the last one. For those reading my solution, I'm gonna try and describe everything I did since the problem presented itself.

- When starting normally, the computer will crash into the blue screen, collect data and restart
- During restart, Windows will try to fix, fail and show a screen that says "Restart" or "Advanced Options";
- I entered Advanced Options and got into the System Restore option, where I tried to restore to "Yesterday". The restoration then failed.
- I repeated the process and selected an older restore point (6 days ago), which was the only other restore point available beside the one that failed.
- The restoration was a success, but the error did not go away;
- Since I have Z: as a Windows Installer partition (like a DVD drive with the CD on it), I booted it, and got into the Troubleshoot -> Refresh option. It then told me that "The Windows Drive was locked".
- I restarted and booted Z: (the installation partition) and press Shift + F10
- Execute: bootrec /fixmbr; bootrec /fixboot; bootrec /rebuildbdc;
- At this point, CMD told me that NONE Windows Installtion had been found, so I did not had to confirm (Y or N) to the command's response.
- I turned on my computer and went into the Advanced Options -> Troubleshoot -> Advanced Mode -> Automatic Repair

It took a while (about 10 minutes), but the computer rebooted and everything was fine.